# нужно сделать модель для работы с JSON yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Есть таблица с полем **options** в формате **Json**. Нужно создать такой класс, который будет наследоваться от ActiveRecord и позволит управлять json объектами как обычными переменными.

нужно создать JsonValidator, но я не знаю как

Например:

```
$user = new User();
$user->options->push = 'on';
$user->options->cash = 'off
...
Так же нужно чтобы можно было писать так
$user->options['push'] = 'on';
$user->options['cash'] = 'of';
```

не знаю как реализовать

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно создавать класс, можете просто сделать json behavior, которому вы будете передавать название json поля и это поведение будет обрабатывать данные перед и после записи, ну и json валидатор нужно будет создать. 
 Полностью реализацию в ответ выкладывать не буду.
Вот уже готовое решение есть github.com/paulzi/yii2-json-behavior

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, Максат! 
Дело в том, что мне нужно создать класс(( Задача стоит в этом.